# What is the name of this type of page layout

Tags: html, css, layout

What is the name of the type of layout that asana uses in the first page? http://asana.com/

The layout in question is basically a long page, divided into sections in which (at least I think thats what happens) each section is more or less the size of the viewport. Sometimes parallax scrolling is included (in this case it doesn't)

This type of layout exists a lot, and its kind of a trend nowadays to do this, I don't know how they do it (without inventing the wheel all over again) and what this method is called

Comment: Reinventing the wheel? There is nothing particularly special about this layout, look at the source code, they are just div blocks with full width that extend vertically.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, this is seemingly nothing too different than what has been already going on - and therefore does not have an official name.

The design techniques that you are explaining are all parts of modern web design trends including a full screen image background in the greeting, parallax scrolling design, and featured information blocking (where there is distinct separation between the information of several different key features of the product/services being marketed).  These combined techniques create a unique experience that provokes the user to scroll through the entirety of the page as if a story is being told, thus proving itself to be nothing but a mere (and seemingly successful) display content strategy.

Answer (score 0):

This year's trend calls it *Single page design* or *One page design*. There exists even a showcase website - http://onepagelove.com/

Otherwise this question is quite funny since as others mentioned - if you browsed the internet years ago almost every page looked like that by functionality - just the design was not that pimped up since browsers couldn't do it. I guess it's a trend thing...